# which internet audio streaming server can I use?

Tags: streaming, encoding, audio

I need an audio streaming setup that supports the following formats: WMA, AAC and MP3. The streams must be compatible both with desktop players like Winamp. Win Media Player and with Flash Player and devices like iPhone, Android, etc.

I'm looking for a single server solution and a single encoder solution that would meet all those requirements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that FFserver can do what you're looking for. It's a part of the open source cross-platform FFmpeg suite, available at http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 2):

Try VLC: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
The most important advantages are: CLI interface + GUI, nearly all OS, remote control over web interface

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [Digital Rapids](http://www.digital-rapids.com/) various products would do what you want but not for free, not sure of any open source equivalents.